# JSON Body query on Invoke-RestMethod Powershell method for Power BI Refresh

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod, powerbi-rest-api

i'm currently developing a Powershell script to refresh a single table partition of my Power BI dataset using a POST API call through the Invoke-RestMethod.

```
# Connect the Service Principal
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $Secret -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object PSCredential $AppId, $password
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Creds -Tenant $TenantId
 
$headers = Get-PowerBIAccessToken

   
#These refreshes are examples to use the API using the Invole-RestMethod function.
$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$GroupId/datasets/$DatasetId"
$DatasetName = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $headers –Method GET | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select name).name

$Query = @"
{  
    "type": "full", 
    "commitMode": "transactional", 
    "objects": [ 
          {
            "database": "$DatasetName",
            "table": "$TableName",
          }
      ],
      "applyRefreshPolicy": "false"  
} 
"@

# Optional
# Refresh the dataset
$uri = $uri+"/refreshes"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $headers –Method POST -Body ($Query | ConvertTo-Json ) -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop

# Check the refresh history
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $headers –Method GET | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty value | Format-Table -Property id, refreshType, startTime, endTime, status

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

The Invoke-RestMethod with post request doesn't read the query and start a full refresh on my Power BI dataset. I got no error but a full refresh instead of a specific table refresh.

Is there something wrong that doesn't allow the script to pass and then execute the predefined query instead a full refresh?

Comment: Your problem is likely with `-Body ($Query | ConvertTo-Json )` - the text stored in `$Query` is already a valid JSON document, piping it to `ConvertTo-Json` turns it into a json string literal (which the API probably just ignores)